# Is it possible to use the reset() API method within the callback methods?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

When using the **jquery.filer** plugin, is it possible to use the reset() API method within the AJAX callback methods?

For example:

```
var fileUpload = $('#file-upload-input').filer({
    uploadFile: {
        url: 'note-media-upload',
        type: 'POST',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        onComplete: function(l, p, o, s, jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log('onComplete');
            fileUpload.reset();
        }
    }
});
```

I get an error:`Uncaught TypeError: fileUpload.reset is not a function`

Comment: What is the error..?

Comment: You can use a callback function that calls `fileUpload.reset();`

Comment: The error was "Uncaught TypeError: fileUpload.reset is not a function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using -

```
$('#file-upload-input').prop('jFiler').reset();
```